# Proving recurrence relations using induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve recurrence relations and then prove them via induction.  I'm a bit stuck on this question.  I'm finding it a bit hard to get it around my head for some reason.  The recurrence relation is
$T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + 1$

And the formula that I got for it is $T(2^k) = 2^{k+1} -1$

So for my induction, I did this:

**Claim:** $T(2^k) = 2^{k+1} -1$

**Base case:**

$k = 1$

$T(2^1) - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1$

Assuming that it's true for some $k$ so proving for $k+1$

**Inductive case:**

$T(2^{k+1})$

$= 2 T(2^{k+1} /2) + 1$

$= 2 T(2^{k+1-1} ) + 1$

$= 2 T (2^k) + 1$

$= 2 T (2^{k+1} -1) + 1$ (From the claim, -1 & +1 cancel out)

$= 2 (2^{k+1} )$

Could anyone tell me whether this would be the correct solution or if I've gone wrong somewhere? I'm a bit unsure on the last step, as I've got $2x (2^k+1)$ which is adding indices so maybe this would  give $2^k+2$ which would be incorrect, but I'm unsure.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the formula you got $2^{k+1}-1$?

Comment: Or $2^k-1$?   $\,2^k+1-1$ would be simply $2^k$

Comment: $2T(2^k)+1=2(2^k-1)+1=2^{k+1}-2+1=2^{k+1}-1$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes sorry the formula should be $T(2^k) = 2^{k+1} -1$

Comment: Is it still wrong where you say “the formula that I got for it is”?

Comment: Yep, didn't notice that initially, changed it now

Comment: Is it $2^{k+1}-1$ or $2^k-1$?  Check the base case

Answer (score 2):

You showed that $2T(2^{k+1})=2T(2^k)+1$.

From the inductive hypothesis, this is $2(2^k-1)+1=2^{k+1}-2+1=2^{k+1}-1$, as desired.